# Why I have to click 2 times to run this function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, animation

This is the code i'm working on, and i don't know why everytime that i refresh the page i need to click 2 times to open the menu. Once i click the second time all works correctly.
This is the html of the button:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("overlay-menu");
x.style.height = "0%";

function showMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("overlay-menu");
  if (x.style.height === "0%") {
    x.style.height = "100%";
  } else {
    x.style.height = "0%";
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: fixed;
  color: #0A0A0A;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s cubic-bezier(.55, .03, .26, 1.01);
}

.nav-menu-text {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #EB761D;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2.8em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="nav-menu-text" onclick="showMenu()">MENU</p>

<div class="overlay-menu" id="overlay-menu">
  <!-- code of the menu -->
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `console.log` to see what is the height on the first click

Comment: Similar question has been answered in this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497385/why-do-i-have-to-click-this-input-button-twice-to-call-a-function

Comment: Just toggle a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.style.height` is probably not "0%" when your code runs, try changing the condition from:

```
if (x.style.height === "0%") {
```

to

```
if (x.style.height !== "100%") {
```