# Why do I have to double click to make sidebar navigation appear?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a sidebar button on my site, and for some reason I have to double-click it in order for it to work. This goes the same for all the other links part of my HTML site when I click on the sidebar.

How the link looks like before I click on it:
`file:///Users/*redacted*/Desktop/HTML/CMS/CMS-CERT.html`

How it looks like after one click:
`file:///Users/*redacted*/Desktop/HTML/CMS/CMS-CERT.html?typeOfCSR=#`

It looks the same after the second click but then the button works and the sidebar navigation opens. (It may work here as I wasn't able to put in the code from the other sites part of the main html)

Also, I have have some typed in some input, after clicking the sidebar, it erases all the input(deletes all the inputted info on the page); I don't want that to happen.

What can I do to fix these problems?

Someone suggested I should use event listener instead of onclick. The problem is I got the JavaScript from somewhere else and am not sure where to insert it.

```css
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #75c3f3;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    text-align:center;
}

#review {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#review:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}

#reset {
    background-color: #af4c4c;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#result {
    width:fit-content;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 370px;
    border: 3px;
    min-height: 70px;
    max-width: 975px;
}

table {
    height: 3px;
}

select {
    margin-left: 20px;
    position:absolute;
}

#typeOfCSR {
    margin-left: 48px;
    position: absolute;
}

#nameOfCert {
    margin-left: 54px;
    position: absolute;
}

#FQDN {
    margin-left: 72px;
    position: absolute;
}

#altName {
    margin-left: 193px;
    position: absolute;
}


#CN {
    margin-left: 168px;
    position:absolute;
}

textarea {
    height: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    max-width:50%;
}

body {
    font-size: large;
    background: #74ebd5;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ACB6E5, #74ebd5);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ACB6E5, #74ebd5); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    min-width: fit-content;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container #input {
    position:relative ;
    margin-right: auto;
    resize: horizontal;;
}

.container {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 720px;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .sidebar a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .sidebar .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  .openbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .openbtn:hover {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  
  #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  

/** linear-gradient(135deg, #71b7e6, #9b59b6) **/
/** #008ce4; **/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />

    <title>CMS Cert Creation Form</title>
</head>

<body> 

    <form action="#"> 

        <div class="container">

            <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
                <a href="CMS-CERT.html">CMS</a>
                <a href="extra.html">Extra</a>
                <a href="extra2.html">Extra2</a>
                <a href="extra3.html">Extra3</a>
              </div>
        
              <div id="main">
                <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>

        <h1>CMS Cert Creation Form</h1>
   
<div id="input">
        <div>
            <label for="typeOfCSR">Choose the type of CSR you want to request</label>
            <select name="typeOfCSR" id="typeOfCSR" onkeyup="allowAlphaNumericSpace(this)">
                <option value="">Select an Option </option>
                <option value="One">One</option>
                <option value="Two">Two</option>
                <option value="Three">Three</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<br />
<br />
        <div>
            <label for="nameOfCert"> Enter the name you want to give to the Cert</label>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="nameOfCert" onkeyup="allowAlphaNumericSpace(this)"></textarea>
        </div>
<br />
<br />
        <div>
            <label for="FQDN"> Enter the FQDN of all your CMS servers</label>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="FQDN" onkeyup="allowAlphaNumericSpace(this)"></textarea>
        </div>
<br />
<br />
        <div>
            <label for="alternateName"> Enter the alternate name</label>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="altName" onkeyup="allowAlphaNumericSpace(this)"></textarea>
        </div>
 <br />
 <br />
        <div>
            <label for="CN"> Enter the CN of your server</label>
            <textarea cols="100" rows="1" id="CN" onkeyup="allowAlphaNumericSpace(this)"></textarea>
        </div>
<br />
<br />

<table id="result">
      <tr height="50px">
        <td>Result will show here</td>
      </tr>
</table>

</div>

<br />
<br />


        <button type="button" id="review">Generate String</button>
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset Input" id="reset">
<br/>
<br/>
    <br />
</form>
      </div>
</div>

    <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById('review');
        btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            let typeOfCSR = document.getElementById('typeOfCSR').value;
            let CN = document.getElementById('CN').value;
            let FQDN = document.getElementById('FQDN').value;
            let altName = document.getElementById('altName').value;
            let nameOfCert = document.getElementById('nameOfCert').value;

            document.getElementById('result').textContent =  typeOfCSR +" "+ nameOfCert +" "+ FQDN +" "+ altName +" "+ CN;
        })

        function allowAlphaNumericSpace(thisInput) {
  thisInput.value = thisInput.value.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/).join('');
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, it opens in one click only.

Comment: I wasn't able to insert the code of the other links, it doesn't work with the other links in it (the links from the navigation)

Comment: If I had to guess, it's a result of using `onclick`. You should consider using an eventlistener  which you're already using for one of your functions so you know how they work. There's a very old and lengthy explanation for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453422/why-does-my-button-need-to-be-clicked-twice-for-the-event-handler-to-work-the-fi?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top but realistically you could jump to the short version which is to just get rid of the onclicks and use eventlistener instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So I use eventlistener instead? I'm actually a complete noob in JavaScript, I got the code from somewhere else... so I wouldn't really know how to replace one set of code for another

Comment: @Vee You've basically got a working example in your code for your review `btn`, but you could read up on how the eventlistener works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and another explanation with functional examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: ty for the resources, I'll check them out